# Dictionary multiplication in PuLP - constraint implementation

Tags: python, pulp

I'm creating a larger LP model, that needs to assign a product k from a production facility i to customer j. I'm having trouble with implementing a constraint related to shipping the products in containers.

z_ij is the amount of containers to ship from location i to j.

x_ijk is the amount of product k shipped from i to j.

If a product fills up 1% of a container, I need the model to know that it should assign 2 containers, if we ship 150 products.

I'm implementing a constraint with a x_ijk decision variable. The sum of the decision variable must be multiplied with a factor for each i and for each j (how much of a container the product takes up).

I tried creating a dictionary called container_cap, showing how much of a container a product takes up. Multiplying that with my decision variable should provide the required amount of containers.

```
#Containers to ship
for i in production:
    for j in warehouse:
            prob += lpSum([x[i][j][k]] * container_cap[k] for k in product) <= lpSum([z[i][j]])
```

However, I get a "Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'"-error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a one-character error in the code above. You have written:

```
prob += lpSum([x[i][j][k]] * container_cap[k] for k in product) <= lpSum([z[i][j]])
```

In this you are trying to multiply a list of one element `[x[i][j][k]]` by a potentially non-integer `container_cap[k]`. This is why you are throwing an error. In python you can duplicate a list n-times over by multiplying it by n. But n has to be an integer.

What I think you wanted to write is:

```
prob += lpSum([x[i][j][k] * container_cap[k] for k in product]) <= lpSum([z[i][j]])
```

Here you are taking a sum of a list of items, with one item for each item `k` in the list `product` which you've presumably already defined, and then saying that list needs to be less than another value.

Also, unless I've misunderstood your model, the second `lpSum` is not necessary. You are basically saying that the number of containers scheduled from `i` to `j` needs to be enough to fit all the product that has been scheduled from `i` to `j`; so I think you want the following:

```
prob += lpSum([x[i][j][k] * container_cap[k] for k in product]) <= z[i][j]
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. Works like a charm now

Comment: No worries! It's customary to mark the answer as correct (the tick) and up vote (the arrows) if helpful.